# Scala - What is this NoSuchMethodError telling me?

Tags: scala

I get a `NoSuchMethodError` when I run my unit test. My Scala code compiles, so why does it fail to find a method during runtime?

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.twitter.algebird.Analytics$.mean(Lscala/Function2;)Lscala/Function1;`

What does the `(Lscala/Function2;)` and `Lscala/Function1;` mean?

Comment: Could you post the code causing it?

Comment: The second question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343593/understanding-method-signature-in-nosuchmethod-exception

Comment: Binary/source incompatibility?

Comment: When using incremental build (like in IntelliJ IDE) it can also mean a broken build after some signature change. A full Rebuild fixes this.

Answer (score 1):

This usually indicates that you are using a binary incompatible library, e.g. your dependencies don't match (you have library A version X and library B that assumes library A version Y).

If you build with sbt, you can run `sbt evicted` that will give you warnings about possibly incompatible libraries.

Comment: If you're using maven you can look at `mvn dependency:tree`, or eclipse has a nice UI for seeing what pulls in a particular library.