# NoDefFound error

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark, pyspark, noclassdeffounderror

I am getting the following errors while running Spark on Hadoop
It is also giving me this error when I use the Scala API. I was convinced that the error is related to Spark paths and CLASSPATH.

The error is:

> stage 0.0 failed 4 times; aborting job   17/04/25 13:36:53 WARN
>   TaskSetManager: Lost task 11.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 20, 10.98.92.150,
>   executor 4): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)    17/04/25 13:36:53 WARN
>   TaskSetManager: Lost task 13.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 21, 10.98.92.150,
>   executor 4): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)    17/04/25 13:36:53 WARN
>   TaskSetManager: Lost task 6.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 6, 10.98.92.150,
>   executor 5): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)    17/04/25 13:36:53 WARN
>   TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, 10.98.92.150,
>   executor 5): TaskKilled (killed intentionally)    Traceback (most recent
>   call last):     File
>   "/opt/apache/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/examples/src/main/python/test.py",
>   line 8, in 
>         hive_context.sql("select count(1)  from src_tmp").show()      File "/opt/apache/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 318, in show       File
>   "/opt/apache/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py",
>   line 1133, in **call**      File
>   "/opt/apache/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py",
>   line 63, in deco    File
>   "/opt/apache/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value  py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error
>   occurred while calling o46.showString.    :
>   org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 5 in stage 0.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 5.3
>   in stage 0.0 (TID 23, 10.98.92.151, executor 2):
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.parquet.CorruptStatistics
>             at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetStatisticsInternal(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:346)
>             at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetStatistics(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:360)
>             at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:816)
>             at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.readParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:793)
>             at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:502)
>             at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:461)
>             at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:417)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.initialize(SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java:107)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.initialize(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:109)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:377)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:351)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:150)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:102)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.scan_nextBatch$(Unknown
>   Source)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown
>   Source)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
>             at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
>             at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
>             at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)        Driver stacktrace:
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1435)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1423)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>             at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>             at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1422)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>             at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:802)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1650)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1605)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1594)
>             at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:628)
>             at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1918)
>             at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1931)
>             at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1944)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:333)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2371)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withNewExecutionId(Dataset.scala:2765)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$execute$1(Dataset.scala:2370)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collect(Dataset.scala:2377)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2113)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2112)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedCallback(Dataset.scala:2795)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2112)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2327)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:248)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>             at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>             at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>             at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
>             at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>             at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>             at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
>             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
>   org.apache.parquet.CorruptStatistics
>             at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetStatisticsInternal(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:346)
>             at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetStatistics(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:360)
>             at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.fromParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:816)
>             at org.apache.parquet.format.converter.ParquetMetadataConverter.readParquetMetadata(ParquetMetadataConverter.java:793)
>             at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:502)
>             at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:461)
>             at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:417)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.initialize(SpecificParquetRecordReaderBase.java:107)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.VectorizedParquetRecordReader.initialize(VectorizedParquetRecordReader.java:109)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:377)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.parquet.ParquetFileFormat$$anonfun$buildReader$1.apply(ParquetFileFormat.scala:351)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.nextIterator(FileScanRDD.scala:150)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileScanRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(FileScanRDD.scala:102)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.scan_nextBatch$(Unknown
>   Source)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithoutKey$(Unknown
>   Source)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown
>   Source)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
>             at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:377)
>             at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
>             at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:126)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
>             at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
>             at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:282)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>             at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>             ... 1 more

Comment: Please copy-paste only relevant track information. All the trace above will not encourage anyone to help you.

Comment: The trace itself is not that bad; if only it was formatted correctly...

Comment: I'm sorry about the formatting, I am new to the forum.

Comment: Looks like your edit retained lots of useless stuff, but dropped the useful error message *(the one that I tried to copy in my answer -- and which appears to have been truncated from the begnning, on second thoughts)*

Answer (score 4):

***EDIT*** *The original answer was actually wrong. Sure, the "classpath first" property is useful in some cases, but not in this one. Thanks for the votes but they are not deserved.*  **:-(**

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.parquet.**SemanticVersion**.(IIILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
>   at org.apache.parquet.**CorruptStatistics**

You are using Spark 2.1.0, which bundles Parquet V1.8.1, which defines its classes in package `org.apache.parquet`.

---

***Original answer (which missed the point)***

Your Hadoop distro seems to be from Cloudera, and (for example) CDH 5.10 bundles Parquet V1.5.0, which defines its classes in package `parquet`.

```
unzip -l $SPARK_HOME/jars/parquet-column-1.8.1.jar | grep CorruptStatistics.class
     3507  07-17-2015 13:56   org/apache/parquet/CorruptStatistics.class

unzip -l /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH/jars/parquet-common-1.5.0-cdh5.10.0.jar | grep SemanticVersion.class
     5406  01-20-2017 11:57   parquet/SemanticVersion.class
```

So these versions are clearly incompatible.

***EDIT*** *So incompatible that they do not interfere, simply because the package is different.*

When you run Spark executors under YARN, by default, the CLASSPATH contains the JARs from both versions of Parquet in random order, with catastrophic results.

Workaround: make sure your Spark JARs have precedence in the CLASSPATH with either

- a command-line option on each execution
  `--conf spark.yarn.user.classpath.first=true`
- or a global entry in `spark-defaults.conf`
  `spark.yarn.user.classpath.first  true`

---

***Better analysis with no real solution at this point*** *(sorry)*

The "NoSuchMethodError" complains that it could not find, at run-time, a method that was present at compile time.
That's for class `SemanticVersion` and a method with no name -- *which is clearly wrong, even a constructor should be be marked with `.<init>` or sthg similar* -- *so I assume the error message got truncated, maybe because of `<` character being swallowed by S.O. message editor when you pasted it*.

The method details: arguments `(int, int, int, String, String, String)` and a return type `void`. See [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8343593/understanding-method-signature-in-nosuchmethod-exception) for reference.

OK, let's assume class `CorruptStatistics` was compiled with a call to `new SemanticVersion(1, 2, 3, "a", "b", "c")` which was valid at compile time, but for some reason, when `SemanticVersion` was compiled, that constructor was not present (release mismatch?!)

That's insane, because the "official" source code (cf. [apache GIT repo](https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=parquet-mr.git;a=tree;hb=4aba4dae7bb0d4edbcf7923ae1339f28fd3f7fcf) under "parquet-column" and "parquet-common") shows no trace of such a constructor, never, ever. Actually the `CorruptStatistics` is a bug fix for compatibility with some buggy Parquet formats, and `SemanticVersion` has just two constructors and no String in these.
Some "non-official" (but easier to read) source code for V1.8.1 can be found [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.parquet/parquet-column/1.8.1/org/apache/parquet/CorruptStatistics.java/) and [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.parquet/parquet-common/1.8.1/org/apache/parquet/SemanticVersion.java/).

Bottom line: all that makes no sense, unless

- Spark 2.1.0 ships with Parquet JARs that are somehow inconsistent *(and nobody found that bug yet!?!)*
- or you built a custom JAR, embedding Parquet classes that you have customised -- or a rogue fork of Parquet invoked in a rogue POM *(??)*
- or you have deployed an exotic Cloudera parcel that places custom Parquet JARs in the CLASSPATH *(but the "user classpath first" trick should have fixed that - unless you have these exotic JARs explicitly in `spark.executor.extraClassPath`)*

To solve that mistery, I strongly suggest that you inspect all JARs that are susceptible to be present at run-time in the YARN CLASSPATH, including your custom JARs + Spark JARs + Cloudera CDH JARs + Cloudera extra parcels JARs, searching for any reference of `CorruptStatistics.class` -- you have the example `unzip -l | grep` command for that; wrap it in a loop, and be ready for surprises.

Comment: Thank you for your response,Samson.I understand the problem now. But I tried doing the global entry and it is still giving me the same error. Anything else I should try?

Comment: Would it help if I was using a different version of Spark?

Comment: @xyz, I have no clue. If you don't find the root cause -- by getting back to the original error message *(which got truncated from your post)* and by scanning all possible JARs in your system to find duplicates of the classes involved (caller + called) then you can try to randomly change a few things, but I'm very pessimistic about the outcome.